# How can I help Canonical be profitable?

Tags: canonical

1. I can buy cloud space from ubuntu one instead of dropbox, etc .... right?
2. Does buying system76 computers help canonical in anyway?

What else can we do? Please add to this list.

Comment: So, why comment just to say that you don't know? If you don't know, just don't comment.

Comment: buy _all_ the things!

Comment: Even I'd like to do it.But shipping to India is like 3 times the price of what I wanted to buy.
I really hope canonical starts to have a re-seller in India too..

Comment: @mikewhatever comment deleted. I just wanted to point out the fact that I have not answered the second part of the question and hoped someone else would answer it.

Answer (score 29):

Canonical provides support services that you can use. Check these links for more details:

[Training](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=21)

[Ubuntu Advantage](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=41)

[Ubuntu Home Support](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=31)

Indirectly, you can convince organisations/companies/universities to switch to Ubuntu by citing the benefits that they will get from free and open source software (FOSS). This way, if these organisations/companies/universities opt for the Canonical Support services, Canonical will get more profits!

Other than support services, you can buy accessories and software (including Ubuntu CD/DVDs) as well from the [Canonical Store](http://shop.canonical.com/) in general.

Comment: +1 for _convince organisations/companies/universities to switch to Ubuntu_

Comment: @rigved - I've rolled back your change - please try not to refer out to other peoples answers unless you can substantially add value to them.

Answer (score 18):

You can buy merchandise on [Canonical Store](http://shop.canonical.com/), there are a lot of good things. I bought some pens, the A5 notebook, and some Ubuntu CDs. Now I'm waiting for Oneiric release for buying CDs with the new beautiful Polo Shirt!

And surely, you can help Canonical spreading Ubuntu, this is the greatest contribuite, specially in business.

Answer (score 6):

1. You can purchase any mp3 music you buy through the Ubuntu One Music Store (accessible via Rhythmbox in ubuntu-10.04 & 10.10 and Banshee in ubuntu-11.04 & 11.10) and/or the Amazon MP3 Store (accessible via Banshee in ubuntu-11.04 & 11.10).
2. You can contribute directly to the ubuntu project. Help is needed in translating materials, creating wikis, developing & writing manuals for how to do things (e.g., I just read one on how to use Ubuntu Software Center), basic sorting of bugs, and so forth. There are many ways to help out even if you don't know how to code.

Answer (score 4):

Where Canonical makes money is in many different areas. The simplest way most can help is to advocate purchasing support - Ubuntu Advantage - especially in the enterprise.

Basically, if you use Ubuntu in your business please contribute. For most businesses that means buying Ubuntu Advantage.